# 2 combobox = 1 selecciona pais y el otro las ciudades del pais seleccionado

Tags: angular, formularios, bootstrap-4, webforms

quiero utilizar es **plugin o libreria** de bootstrap para facilitar el tema de seleccion de paises y ciudades: 
http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/country.html

Me he descargado el zip para poder usarlo pero **no se** donde guardar cada cosa del **archivo.zip**

Dejo unas imagenes de lo que contiene **archivo.zip** :

**Imagen 1**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen 2**

[image: b]

La **libreria** queria usarla para tener **2 combobox** Uno que seleccione **Pais** y otro **Ciudad** . Segun el **pais** que seleccione apareceran unos u otros en el **combobox ciudad**. Busco la manera de hacer eso y encontre esta libreria pero si alguien sabe de otra manera para hacer eso soy todo oidos.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, en ¿qué forma pretendes usar dicha librería? Creo que debes ser un poco más específico. Saludos

Comment: Buenas, solo estoy buscando la forma de añadir a mi formulario algun combobox ya predefinido que me deje seleccionar pais y una vez seleccionado pais que me deje seleccionar ciudad